# MySQL Order by numeric sequence

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a "Location" data set returned by a simple query from a MySQL database:

```
A1
A10,
A2
A3
```

It is sequenced by an "Order By Location" statement.  The issue is that I would like the returned sequence to be:

```
A1
A2
A3
A10
```

I am not sure if this is achievable with a MySQL Order By statement?

Comment: you alwqays have A value in begining ?

Comment: no, not always, however the others are B and C

Comment: ok look my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
order by CAST(replace((Location),'A','') as signed )
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/048db/5)

EDIT:

if you have other letters then A then consider to cut the first letter and order the rest as integers.

```
    ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(loc, 2) as signed )
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/048db/9)

Comment: This has been really helpful.  In the end the following worked perfectly:  ORDER BY SUBSTR(Loc, 1,1), CAST(SUBSTR(Loc, 2, 2) as signed )

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to do this is to order by the length and then the value:

```
order by length(location), location
```

Comment: taking length into account may work for the example given - But if there is a location like `A001` it will fail. However, the provided examples do not clearly mention all possible variations.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ORDER BY SUBSTR(location, 2)
```

Comment: @echo_Me I`ve read in my horoscope that as soon as I hit 7000,my salary will be doubled,my girlfriend will be twice as beautiful and North Korea will renounce nuclear weapons.So it will be a very important event,no doubt.